# Prevent user interaction when adding a package in Solaris

Tags: unix, chef-infra, solaris-10

I am trying to install the chef-client package on Solaris 5.10 Sparc.

when i install it with the command pkgadd -d chef.sparc.solaris chef, it asks me "Do you want to continue with the installation of  [y,n,?]".

How can i avoid this user interaction and install the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's Help site has documentation for that.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-6958/swmgrpkgs-19113/index.html

And just to back up the link there are 2 ways they list, one with an adiministration file like this placed in the current directory or /var/sadm/install/admin ... it also has an option to pass the path of the administration file directly to pkgadd.

```
mail=
instance=overwrite
partial=nocheck
runlevel=nocheck
idepend=nocheck
rdepend=nocheck
space=nocheck
setuid=nocheck
conflict=nocheck
action=nocheck
networktimeout=60
networkretries=3
authentication=quit
keystore=/var/sadm/security
proxy=
basedir=default
```

The other method is to utilize pkgask to store your responses... check the pkgask man page, I figure this is the better way to do it.